# Получение бинарных данных с qr code pdf-417

Tags: java, qrcode

Всем привет. Столкнулся с необходимостью прочесть qr code с бинарными данными. Все сервисы и приложения предостовляют уже в текстовом варианте. Есть ли способ получить байты на прямую?
Можно  на  java.

Comment: zxing же вроде самая известная библиотека

Comment: Насколько я понимаю она с начало конвектит в String, только потом байты, а мне нужны сразу байты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я воспользовался библиотекой zxing , но она не возвращает байты, пришлось посмотреть кодировку (ISO_8859_1) в которой она собирает строку и из полученного строкового результата вызвать `result.getText().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`